# Laravel JSON field can't update or updateOrCreate if not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Using Laravel 5.6. I have JSON field called `metas` Inserting and Updating works as expected except 1 thing: if field doesn't exist in `metas` it will not be created on update or updateOrdCreate methods. Fields that exist updating without problem.

Here is excample `metas` content:

```
{
    "date": "2018-09-17",
    "name": "r08"
}
```

I can update "date" and "name", but there will be some situations where I need to add new field for excample "distance", I can't do this:

```
Registries::where('id', $registry_id)->update([
    'metas->distance' => '200km'
]);
```

Also tried:

```
Registries::where('id', $registry_id)->updateOrCreate([
    'metas->distance' => '200km'
]);
```

No errors.

Comment: Please log the query (when `distance` doesn't exist): `\DB::enableQueryLog(); Registries::where('id', $registry_id)->update(['metas->distance' => '200km']); dd(\DB::getQueryLog());`

Answer (score 3):

Laravel [JSON casting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting) only creates JSON accessor (deserializer) and mutator (serializer) for you:

> Adding the `array` cast to that attribute will automatically deserialize the attribute to a PHP array when you access it on your Eloquent model.
>
> Once the `cast` is defined, you may access the attribute and it will automatically be deserialized from JSON into a PHP array. When you set the value of the attribute, the given array will automatically be serialized back into JSON for storage

So the only way to update a JSON/array field is by overriding its value:

```
$registry = Registries::find($registry_id);
$registry->metas['distance'] = '200km';
$registry->save();
```

or

```
Registries::updateOrCreate(
    ['id', $registry_id], 
    ['metas' => json_encode([
        'date' => '2018-09-17',
        'name'=> 'r08',
        'distance' => '200km',
    ])]
);
```

Comment: Ok but why existing keys can be updated? What you said is plan B.

Comment: Because the mutator (serializer) is triggered during `save`. The mutator serializes the whole `metas` field to JSON string and replaces the old one. While `updateOrCreate` is just a query builder's shorthand method, it does not call any Eloquent feature such as mutator so we need to handle it ourselves (I updated my answer. The previous one is lacking of `json_encode`)

Comment: Well this will work obviously, bet correct answer would be excample in case I need to update or create only 1 key and I don't know whats content is currently saved. So first I need to take out old content, decode it push new element to ir, encode back and save. By the way, you don't need to json_encode here, because I'm using $cast.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try as below. `updateOrCreate()` method needs two array parameter, first one should be identifier and second one should contains update-create data.

```
Registries::updateOrCreate([
    'id' => $registry_id
],[
    'metas->distance' => '200km'
]);
```

Comment: Good point, but no, it still not updating, however other 2 updating.

Answer (score 0):

check the fillable array in your Registries model

Comment: Noup, I added guarded to allow everythibg except ID