# laravel update json query

Tags: arrays, json, laravel, laravel-5

I have mysql db with column that called `"info"`, this is json column.
I have there this json:

```
{ 
   "pizza":{ 
      "sugar":"yes",
      "calorie":"100",
      "protein":"no"
   },
   "hamburger":{ 
      "sugar":"no",
      "calorie":"120",
      "protein":"yes"
   }
}
```

when I want to update for example the calorie of the pizza there is no problem:

```php
DB::table('food')->where('id', '=', '1')
    ->update(array('info->pizza->calorie' => '90'));
```

then in the db i have:

```
{ 
   "pizza":{ 
      "sugar":"yes",
      "calorie":"90",
      "protein":"no"
   },
   "hamburger":{ 
      "sugar":"no",
      "calorie":"120",
      "protein":"yes"
   }
}
```

but when i want to add some food, for example chocolate:

```php
DB::table('food')->where('id', '=', '1')
    ->update(array('info->chocolate->calorie' => '10'));
```

nothing happened.

In which way I can do that? thanks!

Comment: I see a `pizza` object, but I don't see a `chocolate` object anywhere in your code.

Comment: @UdoE. there is no chocolate in the code. i want to add the chocolate like the pizze and the hamburger...

Answer (score 1):

You can't update non-existing keys for json columns in MySQL table. Look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52607995/laravel-json-field-cant-update-or-updateorcreate-if-not-exist) to better understand the reason why.

To solve this problem, your best bet is to retrieve the column json data, decode it, insert new object entry, encode it again and finally update the table with the new json data.

```php
$food = DB::table('food')->where('id', '=', '1')->first();
$info = json_decode($food->info);
$info->chocolate = (object)["calorie"=>"10"];

DB::table('food')->where('id', '=', '1')
    ->update(['info' => json_encode($info)]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Laravel are you using? I'm able to set new keys in JSON cast columns using both 5.7 and 5.8:

User Model:

```php
protected $casts = [
   'phone_numbers' => 'json',
];
```

Updating:

```php
User::first()->phone_numbers;
```

> [
>      'mobile' => '0000000000',
>   ]

```php
User::first()->update(['phone_numbers->office'] => '9999999999']);
User::first()->phone_numbers;
```

> [
>     'mobile' => '0000000000',
>     'office' => '9999999999',
>   ]

Updating nested values:

```php
User::first()->update(['phone_numbers->office->ext'] => '100']);
User::first()->phone_numbers;
```

> [
>     'mobile' => '0000000000',
>     'office' => [
>         'ext' => '100',
>     ],
>   ]

**Edit:** You don't happen to have $fillable set for the `info` column, do you? If so, I believe you'll have to specify each individual property for mass-assignment:

```php
protected $fillable = [
    'info->chocolate',
];
```

You can test it quickly by removing it from $fillable and setting $guarded to an empty array (temporarily):

```php
protected $guarded = [];
```

Comment: There are slightly more opening square brackets than closing brackets. And by the way it doesn't work in laravel 8

Answer (score 0):

I know this is the exact answer, as 2 queries have to be performed on DB. But this is a workaround.

```
$food = DB::table('food')->where('id', '=', '1')->first();
$info = json_decode($food->info, true);
$info['chocolate']['calorie] = 10;
$food->info = json_encode(json_encode($info), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
$food->save();
```